# Shortcut in a constructor

Tags: c#

I don't know how to explain properly, this is what I mean:

I have a class Car

```
Car car = new Car(model: "abc", engineModel: "abd")
```

I watched somebody when they write in the brackets they only write **("")** and it pulls **(model: "")**

How do I do that?

**Edit: Found it's functionality of ReSharper**

Comment: Maybe named arguments documentation can help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: I think you need to read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: Ctrl+Space and Tab are your friends.

Comment: This is a question about an IDE or tool, not a language.

Comment: I found it's functionality of ReSharper, but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can start typing `new Car(`, then Intellisense will show you the constructor parameter names, so if you type `m` and tab, it will complete your input to `model:` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The exact thing I was asking turned out to be functionality of ReSharper, but since I don't want to add anything to visual studio your answer helped me the most